# Change ScrollView Page When Scrolled Horizontally but not Vertically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view that contains 2 UITableViews. In other words, page 0 contains UITableView 0 and page 1 contains UITableView 1. At the top of the view, I have a segmented control. When a user swipes between pages, the highlighted segmented control changes. I.e. when the user is on Page 0 and they change to page 1, the segmented control that is highlighted also changes from page 0 to page 1.

My problem is that when the the current page is "Page 1" and I scroll vertically through my UITableView, my function changes the segmented control index to 0. If the user is on page 1 and they scroll vertically on the UITable, I do not want the index to be changed. I have provided my function to change the segmented control index below.

I have tried including `&& yOffset == 0` to my if statement, however it does not work because I believe Y == 0 for a brief moment in time.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var previousPage : NSInteger = 0
    let pageWidth : CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let fractionalPage = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
    let page = lroundf(fractionalPage)
    let yOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / pageWidth)

    if previousPage != page {
        previousPage = page
        }

    segments.selectedSegmentIndex = previousPage
    segments(nil)
}
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

Solution provided by Dhaval D. works perfectly. Prior to performing the page change, check to see whether or not the scroll was performed by the UITableView. Thank you for your help!

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 // Check whether scrolling is performed by UITableView then ignore page counter related stuff 
 if scrollView != tableView0 && scrollView != tableView1 {
    var previousPage : NSInteger = 0
    let pageWidth : CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let fractionalPage = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
    let page = lroundf(fractionalPage)
    let yOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / pageWidth)

    if previousPage != page {
        previousPage = page
        }

    segments.selectedSegmentIndex = previousPage
    segments(nil)
 }
}
```

Comment: Your table view would ONLY scroll vertically. So don’t add any logic to change the segmented control in `scrollViewDidScroll`. Try to add a swipe gesture to the view controller that contains the segmented control. Change the segmented control in that swipe gesture

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I cannot get swipe gestures to recognize. I think it is due to the UIScrollView. Is there a special way I should try to implement it? I have tried but programmatically and through an IBAction

Comment: I think the correct way to do it is with `UIPageViewController` and segmented control

Comment: Most of the times there are standard options in UIKit that we can make use of. I think just browsing through the documentation as to what is available might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by either matching your `UITableView` objects in your `scrollViewDidScroll` like below or you can compare your `UIScrollView` object for which you want to calculate PageNo or you want to change segment control for showing current selection.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 // Check whether scrolling is performed by UITableView then ignore page counter related stuff 
 if scrollView != tableView0 && scrollView != tableView1 {
    var previousPage : NSInteger = 0
    let pageWidth : CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let fractionalPage = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
    let page = lroundf(fractionalPage)
    let yOffset = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y / pageWidth)

    if previousPage != page {
        previousPage = page
        }

    segments.selectedSegmentIndex = previousPage
    segments(nil)
 }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Updated question to include answer. Thank you for your help!